# Facebook tab not showing in my website inside my website

Tags: asp.net, facebook

i have recently added a facebook tab in the bottom of my web page and it was working but now it has stopped working on it own

here is the code:

```
<script>(function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.9";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>




<section class="4u 6u$(medium) 12u$(small)">
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://facebook.com/MunicipalityOfAnkoun/" data-tabs="timeline" data-width="300" data-height="300" data-small-header="true" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true"><blockquote cite="https://facebook.com/MunicipalityOfAnkoun/" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><a href="https://facebook.com/MunicipalityOfAnkoun/">‎name (municipality of ankoun)‎</a></blockquote></div>
                        </section>
```

its showing me the link button not showing the page util i press the link and go back to the page

Comment: Is this code just supposed to serve as a link to the Facebook page?

Comment: I doubt Facebook wants their site showing up inside yours...probably an HTTP header requesting browsers don't do that.

Comment: no it should show a small tab the show the facebook page of the selected tab

Comment: this is the link that facebook shows you how to do it mason : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you may be doing more work than you need!

The Facebook Developers page says that all you need is to add the code they generate after your initial `<body>` tag!

So your code might ressemble:

```
<html>
    <body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function (d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.9";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


        <div class="fb-page"></div>

    </body>


</html>
```

With the `<div class="fb-page"></div>` element wherever you want the Facebook tab to be!

Hope this helps!